# Pop3MailReciever is not deleting messages

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, spring-integration

I'm connecting to a POP3 mail server using the Pop3MailReciever in Spring Integration. I want to delete the message after processing it. I tried setting the ShouldDeleteMessages flag, but it does not delete the message. 
This is the code doing the polling:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EmailPollerApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EmailPollerApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
IntegrationFlow pollingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(mailReceivingMessageSource(), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(60000L)))
            .transform(mailTransformer())
            .transform(requestTransformer())
            .handle(wsGateway())
            .channel("nullChannel")
            .get();
}

@Bean
MailReceivingMessageSource mailReceivingMessageSource(){

    Pop3MailReceiver pop3MailReceiver = new Pop3MailReceiver("mailserver.example.com", 110, "username", "password");

    pop3MailReceiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(true);
    pop3MailReceiver.setMaxFetchSize(1);

    MailReceivingMessageSource mailReceivingMessageSource = new MailReceivingMessageSource(pop3MailReceiver);
    return mailReceivingMessageSource;
}
```

This is the code from Pop3MailReciever that is supposed to be deleting the message:

```
@Override
protected void deleteMessages(Message[] messages) throws     MessagingException {
    super.deleteMessages(messages);
    // expunge deleted mails, and make sure we've retrieved them before closing the folder
    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        new MimeMessage((MimeMessage) messages[i]);
    }
}
```

The super.deleteMessages(message) is setting the DELETED flag on the messages. This is all well and good, but nothing is happening on the server. I had tcpdump going while my app was running and the DELE POP3 command was never run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `mail.debug` javamail property to `true` and look at the output.

I just ran a test with no problems...

```
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "localhost", port 52026, isSSL false
+OK POP3
CAPA
+OK
USER
.
DEBUG POP3: server doesn't support TOP, disabling it
DEBUG POP3: authentication command trace suppressed
DEBUG POP3: authentication command succeeded
2015-09-01 08:14:21,913 Pop3MailReceiver [task-scheduler-1] : opening folder [pop3://user:*****@localhost:52026/INBOX]
STAT
+OK 1 3
2015-09-01 08:14:21,914 Pop3MailReceiver [task-scheduler-1] : attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]
NOOP
+OK
2015-09-01 08:14:21,927 Pop3MailReceiver [task-scheduler-1] : found 1 new messages
RETR 1
+OK
To: foo@bar
From: bar@baz
Subject: Test Email

foo
.
2015-09-01 08:14:21,930 Pop3MailReceiver [task-scheduler-1] : Received 1 messages
2015-09-01 08:14:21,930 Pop3MailReceiver [task-scheduler-1] : USER flags are not supported by this mail server. Flagging message with system flag
NOOP
+OK
DELE 1
+OK
QUIT
+OK
```

Comment: I did that and the output was very similar except for the important part. This is the tail end of the session:
`test  
.  
NOOP  
+OK
QUIT  
+OK`

Comment: Hmmm - what version of Spring Integration? What version of javamail? I tested with the 4.2 snapshot and javamail 1.5.2.

Comment: Im using Spring Integration 4.1.5 and javamail 1.4.7. I have found the problem though. AbstractMailReceiver has its folderOpenMode set to Folder.READ_ONLY. The only place its set to Folder.READ_WRITE is in the onInit() method but that is never called. Do you know the appropriate way to have AbstractMailReceiver open the Folder in read/write mode?

Comment: Ahhh - you should define the `Pop3MailReceiver` as a `@Bean`, so the framework will initialize it. Then `new MailReceivingMessageSource(pop3MailReceiver());` in the `MessageSource` `@Bean`.